# How new ethers came in existence on rinkbey testnet?

Tags: solidity, metamask, rinkeby

Hi I know we can get some ether requesting the automated rinkbey faucet but apart from that is there any way we can mine ethers on rinkbey and if we cannot mine them then what dictates transfer or addition of new ether on the testnet?

Comment: I searched for that and couldnt find it, now I cant even delete it, What are my options?

Comment: Do not worry, it will be marked as duplicated and a link added to the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Rinkeby is a [Clique Proof of Authority](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225) testnet, which means that only those who were explicitly granted authority can get ether from the network. There is no mining, and the only way to get ether is through the faucet.

In contrast, you *can* mine ether on the [Ropsten Proof of Work testnet](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/).